# How to subtract two dates in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

Consider this code. I have this query in a 3T Studio aggregate query.

```
{
    "book.newpublisheddate": {$subtract : [ {$date: "book.published"}, {$date: "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000"}] }
}
```

I cannot use code like `{$subtract : [ "book.published", new Date()] }` because it says it is not valid json. I am using mongo 3.6.13.

Answer (score 1):

Using this collection:

```
> db.test.find()
{
  "_id": 0,
  "book": {
    "published": ISODate("2019-08-04T22:49:14.416Z")
  }
}
```

This aggregation works:

```
> db.test.aggregate([
    {$project:
      {dateDiff: {$subtract: ['$book.published', ISODate('1970-01-01')] }}}
  ])
{ "_id": 0, "dateDiff": NumberLong("1564958954416") }
```

Note that you don't need to surround `book.published` inside a `$date`, rather just use `$book.published`. You also need `ISODate('1970-01-01')`.

This works inside Studio3T "shell mode" and inside the `mongo` shell.

Answer (score 0):

No idea where do you want to use `{$subtract : [ "book.published", new Date()] }`. Assuming it is mongo shell - most likely you are missing a dollar sign before `"book.published"`. Try `"$book.published"` - use `$` to reference fields.